# Django migrate Integer to BigInteger

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I am using South for migrations.

Is it possible to edit a field, that was previously using IntegerField as its datatype to use BigIntegerField as its datatype?

Does south support such migrations or will I have to perform multiple migrations for the same (Adding another column followed by a data migration and finally dropping the old column)?

Comment: You should not have a problem with that, but you can always test with a local sandbox and see if everything is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The South docs [appear to support this change](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autodetector.html#field-changes):

> South will detect if you change a field, and should correctly change
>   the field type, with one exception:
>
> If you alter to a field with a CHECK constraint (e.g.
>   PositiveIntegerField) the constraint won’t be added to the column (it
>   is removed if you alter away, however). This will be fixed in a future
>   release.